# Odd of collision using UuidCreateSequential / NewSequentialID

Tags: sql-server, guid

What are the odds of a collision when using `UuidCreateSequential`, or it's wrapper `NewSequentialID`?  The most specific I've found for sequential guids is "more likely than random guids".

Compare that to random guids, version 4 -- where there are a ton of fun statistics:

- 70-Trillion Guids has a 0.0000000004% chance of collision. The same as the annual odds of being hit by a meteorite ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates))
- 1 billion PCs generating 1-million guids a year has good odds of collision after 70,000 years ([lipper, guids part 3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/05/07/guid-guide-part-three.aspx))
- 2,600,000,000,000,000,000 generations gives 1% chance of a collision

But what about dear old sequential guids?  where are his fun statistics? If relevant, assume a modern version of SQL - say 2012/2014 and windows 2008 or 2012.

Comment: Zero. Rather play the lottery than betting on Guid collisions.

Comment: In 2012+ I would forget about guids entirely and switch to a sequence. The only realistic reason to need guids is for replication or distributed systems. If you are on a single database there is really no good reason to use one.

Comment: @usr - My money to purchase lotto tickets is significantly more finite than computing resources at my disposal. Zero is witty but inaccurate.

Comment: @SeanLange - although sequences are a great addition (I remember them in oracle in 1997!), my particular use case does have distributed issues making them impractical.

Comment: Then make sure your guid column is not your clustered index as index fragmentation is staggering for a guid column. If you use NewSequentialID the fragmentation is barely noticeable but you lose the randomness so that would not be practical in your situation either.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are doing something silly like not having a network card in your server (or setting the mac address explicitly and duplicating macaddrs) you will not get duplicates. If you don't have a network card, the guids will be unique for that machine.

Read the [ms documention page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx) carefully, it says,

"Each GUID generated by using NEWSEQUENTIALID() is unique on that computer. GUIDs generated by using NEWSEQUENTIALID() are unique across multiple computers only if the source computer has a network card."

You have to read between the lines a little, but they really are unique if you are not doing the silly things.

ADDED COMMENT

There is one obvious caveat, the MS docs might be in error. But proving it could take a very long time if you have to disproof by generating a duplicate. It is entirely possible that ms does not use a generate modern guid and may be exposing the underlying mac address. I seem to have misplaced my code of the source code and can't check for certain. :-)